# Get Binary File List from Remote server

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm developing a system that need to download binary files from a server folder. In here I will check before downloading whether they are in my local folder.so I need to get list of the ***.bin** files.

I have tried code in below, but it generate list all the files that on server folder.

```
    private string[] GetRemoteFileList()
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_remoteHost));
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePass);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        string FileNames = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string[] Files = Regex.Split(FileNames, "\r\n");
        return Files;
    }
```

What I need is filter out only *.bin files. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? The code above shows no attempt to only return files with `.bin` extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried?

You have now in `Files` an array of all files in the current directory. Why don't you filter that list? For example:

```
return Files.Where(
    f => f.EndsWith(".bin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                  ).ToList();
```